# numpy standard deviation stacked arrays

Tags: python, numpy, load

What is the most efficient way to calculate the standard deviation at each entry in a vertically stacked numpy array?

```
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Each inner array is several thousand elements long, and I have several thousand of these stacked.
I calculate the mean of each column with:

`avg = np.mean(data, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean?:

```
np.std(data, axis=0)
```

For example:

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> np.std(data, axis=0)
array([ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5])
```